# A set object with user-defined predicate inside class definition

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I'm a C++ beginner and I'm trying to implement the Kruskal's Algorithm for finding the minimum spanning tree of a weighted (connected) undirected graph.

I began by creating a `WeightedGraph` class.

```
class WeightedGraph
{
private:
    int V;
    map<pair<int, int>, int> w_map;

public:
    // constructors and other member functions.
};
```

Initially I defined the private data member named `w_map` above for holding the weight of each edge. That is, if `{u, v}` is a graph edge, then `w_map[{u, v}]` gives a reference to this edge's weight.

One of the steps of the Kruskal's algorithm is the sorting of all the edges in the graph by nondecreasing order of their weights.

As far as I understand, a `map` is only sorted by key (either with the default `<` operator or the with a user-defined binary predicate). A `map` can't directly be sorted by `mapped_value`. Please, correct if I'm wrong here.

One option is to define and use, along with the `w_map` above, a `set<pair<pair<int, int>, int>` (let name it `w_set`), providing it our own predicate so that each element `a` from `w_map` is copied into `w_set` according to the value of `a.second` (its weight).

So if our predicate is this:

```
bool Comparer(const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &a, const pair<pair<int, int>, int> &b)
{
    return a.second < b.second;

}
```

then we can define `w_set` as follows:

```
set<pair<pair<int, int>, int>, decltype(Comparer)*> w_set(Comparer);
```

and use it in a member function for accessing the iterators of the private member `w_map`.

But

I was thinking, what if instead of

- Using a `map` for storing edges and weight.
- Defining a member function for only returning a set with the edges sorted by weight.

we use directly a set of the same type as `w_set` as a data member of `WeightedGraph`. In that case, at each element insertion the set will be sorted as expected.

So the thing I did was this:

```
class WeightedGraph
{
private:
    int V;
    set<pair<pair<int, int>, int>, decltype(Comparer)*>w_sorted(Comparer);

public:
    // constructors and other member functions.
};
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Unknown type name 'SortByWeight'
```

not recognizing `SortByWeight` that was passed as the `comp` parameter to the `set` constructor.

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I think I'm messing with something pretty obvious (with scopes maybe) but I can't figure out what.

Comment: What is the `SortByWeight` type? Where is it defined?

Comment: Initialize it in the default constructor i.e `WeightedGraph() : w_sorted(SortByWeight) {}` or use a brace-or-equal initializer `w_sorted{SortByWeight}`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ups! `Comparer` and `SortByWeight` are the same function. I confused the function names. I fixed it.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing types with function arguments. A [MCVE] will tell us for sure.